# Changing column values for each unique value based on a condition

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach

I have a dataset where I need to change one column values based on a condition.

```
columna columnb 
Y123    B
Y123    A
Y123    T
Y124    B
Y124    A
Y124    T
Y125    A
Y126    A
```

I am trying to write a for loop (or simpler) to iterate over `columna` and for each unique value, if B and T are not present such as with the value Y125 and Y126, replace the A with a T

```
for(ii in 1:length(unique(data$columna)){
  if (data$columnb != "B" & data$columnb != "T"){
    marketf$columnb = "T"
  }
}
```

I suppose this looks completely wrong but I tried many things including for each and other loops but nothing really worked.

Comment: can yoou show the expected output

Comment: if neither B, A, T are present, how can one replace A by a T?

Comment: apologies. if B and T are not present, replace the A by T

Answer (score 2):

After grouping by 'columna', we can `replace` the 'columnb' values where the number of distinct elements is less than 3 and is equal to 'A' to 'T'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(columna) %>%
   mutate(columnb = replace(columnb, n_distinct(columnb) <3 & 
                              columnb =='A', 'T'))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   columna [4]
#  columna columnb
#  <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Y123    B      
#2 Y123    A      
#3 Y123    T      
#4 Y124    B      
#5 Y124    A      
#6 Y124    T      
#7 Y125    T      
#8 Y126    T
```

If we are specifically looking for 'B' and 'T'

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(columna) %>%
    mutate(columnb = replace(columnb, !any(c('B', 'T') %in% columnb)
           & columnb == 'A',  'T'))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   columna [4]
#  columna columnb
#  <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Y123    B      
#2 Y123    A      
#3 Y123    T      
#4 Y124    B      
#5 Y124    A      
#6 Y124    T      
#7 Y125    T      
#8 Y126    T
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(columna = c("Y123", "Y123", "Y123", "Y124", "Y124", 
"Y124", "Y125", "Y126"), columnb = c("B", "A", "T", "B", "A", 
"T", "A", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```